# how to run an executable with python json

Tags: python, json, linux, parsing, terminal

so I have this executable binary file that can be run via terminal
and by python
using code

```
$`python3 shell_c.py`
```

where python file contains

```
 import subprocess

def executable_shell():
    x=subprocess.run('cd build && ./COSMO/methane_c0.outmol.cosmo', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(x)
executable_shell()
```

where COSMO is my executable name and "methane_c0.outmol" is the dynamic value that should be changed along with ".cosmo" which is an extension)

so to get these values from the JSON file I have created a JSON file
with input

```
{
    "root_directory": "C:\\Users\\15182\\cosmo theory\\COSMO\\UDbase8",
    "file_name": "methane_c0",
    "file_format": ".cosmo",
    "output1": "N_atoms",
    "output2": "total number of segments"
}
```

now all that is left is to pass the value of file_name and file_format to the subprocess code to run it.
but I am not getting how to do go about it.

code I have written so far is basic

```
   import json
        with open ("parameters.json") as file:
            data =json.load(file)
        print(type(data))
        pront(data)
```

how should I go so that values can be passed to a python file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import json
import subprocess

with open ("parameters.json") as file:
    data =json.load(file)
dynamic_file_name = data['file_name']+'.outmol'+data['file_format']

def executable_shell():
    x=subprocess.run('cd build && ./COSMO/'+dynamic_file_name, shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(x)
executable_shell()
```